# Cambiar color lineas de fonto React ChartJS 2

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

Tengo un grafico creado en React con la libreria de ChartJS y no se como cambiar el color de las linaes del fondo y los datos de la izquierda(adjunto imagen)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto el codigo del componente:

```js
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import {
    Chart as ChartJS,
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale,
    PointElement,
    LineElement,
    Title,
    Tooltip,
    Legend,
    Filler,
} from 'chart.js';

var beneficios = [3, 5, 7, 4, 8, 9, 5, 3, 7, 5];
let contador=0;

import React, { Component } from 'react'

const HumedadComponent = (props) => {
    ChartJS.register(
      CategoryScale,
      LinearScale,
      PointElement,
      LineElement,
      Title,
      Tooltip,
      Legend,
      Filler
  );

  var meses = ["Humedad(%)", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",];

  var midata = {
      labels: meses,
      datasets: [ // Cada una de las líneas del gráfico
          {
              label: 'Humedad',
              data: beneficios,
              tension: 0.5,
              fill : true,
              borderColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(220, 221, 225, 0.5)',
              pointRadius: 5,
              pointBorderColor: 'rgba(220, 221, 225)',
              pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(19, 15, 64)',
          }
      ]
  };

  var misoptions = {
      scales : {
          y : {
              min : 0
          },
          x: {
            ticks: { color: 'rgba(220, 221, 225)'}
          }
      }
  };

  return (
    <Line data={midata} options={misoptions}/>
    );
};

export default HumedadComponent
```

No se que tengo que cambiar para cambiar las lineas del fondo, los datos de la izquierda y el titulo de arriba a blanco. En el objeto miData esta toda la configuracion del grafico pero no se que tengo que agregar para cambiar ese parametro en especifico. Ya me lei toda la documentacion y no encuentro nada!

Answer (score 0):

Para cambiar el color de las líneas de fondo, los datos de la izquierda y el título de arriba a blanco en el gráfico, puedes agregar algunas opciones al objeto `misoptions`.

Para cambiar el color del título, puedes agregar la opción `color` a la propiedad `title`. Por ejemplo:

```
var misoptions = {
      scales : {
          y : {
              min : 0,
              ticks: {
                  color: 'white'
              }
          },
          x: {
            ticks: {
                color: 'white'
            }
          }
      },
      plugins: {
          title: {
              color: 'white'
          }
      }
  };
```

Para cambiar el color de las líneas de fondo, puedes agregar la opción `color` a la propiedad `grid`. Por ejemplo:

```
var misoptions = {
      scales : {
          y : {
              min : 0,
              ticks: {
                  color: 'white'
              }
          },
          x: {
            ticks: {
                color: 'white'
            }
          }
      },
      plugins: {
          title: {
              color: 'white'
          }
      },
      elements: {
          line: {
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(220, 221, 225, 0.5)',
              borderColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'
          }
      },
      layout: {
          padding: {
              top: 50,
              bottom: 50
          }
      },
      grid: {
          color: 'white'
      }
  };
```

Con estas opciones agregadas, deberías poder cambiar el color de las líneas de fondo, los datos de la izquierda y el título de arriba a blanco. Además, también puedes ajustar la opción de `layout` para agregar un padding superior e inferior para que el título y los datos no se superpongan.